# Selecting first x characters in PowerShell with a catch

Tags: powershell, substring

`$a` is going to be something like "Corners" or "special corners", but could be as long as something like "Standard Window Openings up to 37" which means a simple `Substring()` won't work (that I'm aware of anyway) if I want to find up to the first 20 characters in `$a` (that's the catch).

I found this bit is designed to do what I want, but it just gives me

> "char[] ToCharArray(), char[] ToCharArray(int startIndex, int length)"

and I don't know how to make it function correctly.

```
($a.ToCharArray | select -First 20) -join ""
```

Comment: `-join $a[0..19]`

Comment: @LotPings - wow! i learned something new! [*grin*] i was expecting that to give an out of bounds error ... that is such a _nice_ solution to the OPs problem.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: By default, you indeed don't get an out-of-bounds error, but note that if you activate `Set-StrictMode -Version 3` or higher, you do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is no `.ToCharArray` *property* for strings. what you used will give you the overloads for that method. [*grin*] try typing in a quoted string, adding a dot, and seeing what all shows up.

what you want is the `.ToCharAray()` *method*.

so, add those missing parens to the call and it will work. [*grin*]

also, you really ought to use the "in front" version of the `-join` string operator in that situation. the "behind" version is for adding a delimiter. look at the differences [both give the same result] ...

- `-join ('Standard Window Openings up to 37'.ToCharArray() | Select-Object -First 20)`
- `('Standard Window Openings up to 37'.ToCharArray() | Select-Object -First 20) -join ''`

the 1st example is a better fit for your actual goal.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the information it was very helpful.

Comment: @Zach - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]

Comment: You could also cast to an array of chars `-join ([char[]]$a |Select-Object -First 20)` or `-join ([char[]]'Standard Window Openings up to 37' |Select-Object -First 20)`

Answer (score 14):

Just do it:

```
$a.Substring(0, [Math]::Min($a.Length, 20))
```

Answer (score 7):

[Lee_Dailey's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53021116/45375) explains the problem with your attempt well and offers a working solution, including one using the *unary* form of `-join`.

Just to spell out for future readers ***why* using just `.Substring()` is *not* an option** for implementing extract-*at most*-N-chars. logic: **attempting to extract a substring *beyond the length of the input string* causes an *exception***:

```bash
# OK: -> 'ab'
'abc'.Substring(0, 2)

# !! Exception, because at most 3 chars. can be extracted
# !! "[...]: Index and length must refer to a location within the string. [...]"
'abc'.Substring(0, 4)
```

Your approach to **solving that problem using a *pipeline* with `Select-Object` is a bit heavy-handed**, though.

Below are better-performing alternatives that use *expressions*.

---

**[Esperento's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53025250/45375)** offers the **best-performing solution, using .NET features only**, though it is a bit "noisy" in that it requires a nested method call and a variable (rather than a literal) as input, because that variable must be referenced in the nested method call.
The approaches below are more PowerShell-idiomatic.

[LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings), in a comment, offers a concise solution based on the fact that **strings can *implicitly* be treated as character arrays**, so *array slicing* can be applied; note that indices are *`0`-based*:

```bash
# -> 'ab'
-join 'abc'[0..1] 

# -> 'abc'
# Always-safe equivalent of: 
#   'abc'.Substring(0, 4)
-join 'abc'[0..3]
```

Range expression `0..3` evaluates to array `0, 1, 2, 3`, causing the characters at the specified indices to be returned as a character array which `-join` then reassembles into a string.

**By default, PowerShell *ignores* indices outside the bounds of arrays**, but the
*caveat* is that **if `Set-StrictMode -Version 3` or higher is in effect, the above too will cause an error**.

---

A ***better-performing* alternative that is not sensitive to `Set-StrictMode`** is to **use the `-replace` operator with a regex** (regular expression).
That said, this solution is **somewhat *obscure***.

```bash
# -> 'ab'
# Equivalent of:
#   'abc'.Substring(0, 2)
'abc' -replace '(?<=.{2}).+' 

# -> 'abc'
# Always-safe equivalent of:
#   'abc'.Substring(0, 4)
'abc' -replace '(?<=.{4}).+'
```

- `.{4}` matches exactly `4` characters (`.`) (implicitly) at the start of the string, without including those characters in the match (`(?<=...)`, a look-behind assertion); `.+` then matches all remaining characters (one or more).
- The net effect is that all input strings with *more than 4* characters have everything *from the 5th character* replaced with the *empty string* (due to absence of a replacement operand), leaving effectively just the *first 4* characters.
- Input strings with *4 or fewer* characters are passed through as-is (no extraction needed).

For ***multi-line* input strings**, a little more work is needed (inline option `(?s)` to make `.` match newlines (`` `n ``) too):

```bash
# Extracts the first 3 chars, the equivalent of:  "a`nb"
"a`nbc" -replace '(?s)(?<=.{3}).+'
```

---

Also consider use of a **simple helper function**:

```bash
function substr ([string] $String, [int] $Start = 0, [int] $Length = -1) {
  if ($Length -lt -1 -or $Start -lt 0) { # Quietly output '' for invalid arguments.
    ''
  } elseif ($Length -eq -1 -or $Start + $Length -ge $String.Length) {
    $String.Substring($Start)
  } else {
    $String.Substring($Start, $Length)
  }
}
```

Note that you need to call it with [*argument-mode syntax*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#argument-mode) (shell-like, whitespace-separated arguments), as with any function in PowerShell:

```bash
# -> 'ab'
# Same as: 
#   substr abc 0 2 
#   substr -String abc -Start 0 -Length 2
substr 'abc' -Length 2

# -> 'abc'
substr 'abc' -Length 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Old Question, but including my .Net Regex Method in case it helps anyone.

`[Regex]::Match($a,'.{1,4}').Value`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to worry about whether StrictMode -Version 3 or higher is in effect which will cause `-join $a[0..19]` to error on strings shorter than 20, you can just use an if statement

```
if ($a.Length -gt 20) { $a = $a.Substring(0,20) }
```